# Reading more seeded points in Image Processing

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm new to image processing and C++ and I must implement an application for **Seeded region growing using multiple seed points**.
I must read the seed points via mouse double clicks. I need to read more seed points and I have a problem. I'm trying to read them in a FOR LOOP but it reads only one points several times(as much as the FOR LOOP runs).

```
void CDibView::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    BEGIN_SOURCE_PROCESSING;
    CPoint pos[10];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        pos[i] = GetScrollPosition() + point;

        int x= pos[i].x;
        int y= dwHeight-pos[i].y-1;

        if(x > 0 && x < dwWidth && y > 0 && y < dwHeight)
        {
            CString info;
            info.Format("x=%d,y=%d,color=%d", x, y, lpSrc[y * w + x]);
            AfxMessageBox(info);
        }
    }

    END_SOURCE_PROCESSING;
    CScrollView::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);
}
```

This is what I've tried. What is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a `pos` vector to your class to save your points:

```
class CDibView
{
    ...
    std::vector<CPoint> pos;
};
```

then remove the `for` loop in the double click event handler, saving to `pos` your double click position:

```
void CDibView::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    BEGIN_SOURCE_PROCESSING;

    CPoint p = GetScrollPosition() + point;
    pos.push_back(p); // the current point is added to the vector

    int x = p.x;
    int y = dwHeight - p.y - 1;

    if(x > 0 && x < dwWidth && y > 0 && y < dwHeight)
    {
        String info;
        info.Format("x=%d,y=%d,color=%d", x, y, lpSrc[y * w + x]);
        AfxMessageBox(info);
    }

    END_SOURCE_PROCESSING;
    CScrollView::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);
}
```

Then anywhere in your class you can refer to `pos[i]` to access your point coordinates (but check vector bounds first).